# How can i capture request headers using Bash

Tags: bash

I need to make a script that can get a access token located in the request headers of a website can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what exactly you want?

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to achieve this by piping your curl output through **grep** and **cut** commands. Here I have captured the value of **Content-Length** header.

```sh
curl -s -I example.com | grep "Content-Length" | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Below is a sample script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DOMAIN="example.com"
HEADER="Content-Length"

HEADER_VALUE=$(curl -s -I $DOMAIN | grep $HEADER | cut -d ':' -f 2)
echo $HEADER_VALUE
```

Comment: Please be kind to mark this as correct if this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `curl` with option `-I`:

Example:

```
$ curl -I stackoverflow.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 143
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
X-Request-Guid: 2396f2a8-3398-4264-9b26-ad79f282cb71
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 06:49:12 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1522-HHN
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1554706153.814312,VS0,VE79
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=e68f14b2-d35a-6ca6-8e8d-0b3f936049b4; domain=.stackoverflow.com; 
expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```